# Unable click on load more button which contains href = javascript void using python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to extract all the URLs data from the webpage 'https://careers.wipro.com/search-for-jobs.aspx?div=Technologies&#divhere'  This website contains a 'load more' button which loads more pages.
iI tried the below code to load all the pages first by clicking load more button

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://careers.wipro.com/search-for-jobs.aspx?div=Technologies&#divhere")

main_menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#DivVeiwMore .button-show-more').click()

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(main_menu).click().build().perform()
```

the above code gave below error.

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (455, 863). Other element would

then I tried using the below code

```
url = "https://careers.wipro.com/search-for-jobs.aspx? 
div=Technologies&#divhere"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
page_num = 0

while driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#DivVeiwMore .button-show-more'):
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#DivVeiwMore .button-show-more').click()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
page_num += 1
print("getting page number" +str(page_num))
time.sleep(10)
```

html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
the above code gave me another error
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (455, 863). Other element would receive the click: ...
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)

then I tried using wait but it didn't work as well.please find the code and error below

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://careers.wipro.com/search-for-jobs.aspx? 
div=Technologies&#divhere")

main_menu = 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href="javascript:void(0);"]').click()

#actions = ActionChains(driver)
#actions.move_to_element(main_menu).click().build().perform()

wait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
'a[href="javascript:void(0);"]'))).click()
```

this gave me an error 
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

I am not sure where i am going wrong can anyone help me how to click on Load More button and load all pages so i can extract all href elements from the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is observed that notification of accepting cookie is interrupting the click and you are not waiting for loading the element.

there are different approach but i have used 1 Webdriverwait .
Check if below lines work for you...

Change your driver path

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

opt=webdriver.ChromeOptions()

opt.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chrome driver\\chromedriver.exe",options=opt)
driver.get("https://careers.wipro.com/search-for-jobs.aspx?div=Technologies&#divhere")

# if Accept cookie and decline cookie notification is visible in 5 sec then click on decline 
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="DivCookie"]/div/div/div/a[2]/button')))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="DivCookie"]/div/div/div/a[2]/button').click()
except TimeoutException:
    pass

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#DivVeiwMore .button-show-more')))
time.sleep(1) # just to ensure element is properly loaded
main_menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#DivVeiwMore .button-show-more').click()
# you can use Action chain as well
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, Thank you very much for the assistance.

Comment: How did you find the xpath of cookie element??

Comment: In chrome right click the element , hover on copy... You can do it manulay as well search in google....Mark the anser if it resolved the issu, there is right sign ...

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to deal with webpages that dosent show i decline button but just have i accept buttion the one like the screenshot that i attached..?

Comment: it will be automatically passed after 5 sec .... by try and except block...so if it is visible it will decline if not , it goes on waiting 5 minute..